# How to select the maximum quarter from the result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of period for each quarter for many years, I need to select the maximum period from the result.

Say for example, the actual data would be like this;

```
**period description**
2014 Q2
2014 Q1
2018 Q3
2016 Q1
2017 Q4
2018 Q4
```

Here I need to fetch only the latest quarter in the given data..i.e. we need to get 2018 Q4.

I tried :

```
select substring  (perioddescription, 1, 4)
```

but I've a string in between them so any help would be much appreciated.thanks in advacne

Comment: The top 1 ordered by period description desc? If that's a single text field that's consistent.

Comment: Lexycographical ordering of this string should work because of the format you have. Is `YYYY QX` the exact format?

Comment: thanks ZorgoZ and yes it is the exact value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select top 1 * from tablename
order by cast(left(perioddescription,4) as int) desc,cast(right(perioddescription,1) as int) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach using custom `ORDER BY` clause:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [Period] varchar(7)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   ([Period])
VALUES   
   ('2014 Q2'),
   ('2014 Q1'),
   ('2018 Q3'),
   ('2016 Q1'),
   ('2017 Q4'),
   ('2018 Q4')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [Period]   
FROM #Data
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING([Period], 1, 4)) * 10 + 
   CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING([Period], 7, 1)) DESC
```

Output:

```
-------
Period
-------
2018 Q4
```

Notes: If you are not sure, that all your data is in `yyyy Qq` format, use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [Period]   
FROM #Data
ORDER BY 
   COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING([Period], 1, 4)), 0) * 10 + 
   COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING([Period], 7, 1)), 0) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple MAX function can give you the desired output-

```
SELECT MAX(period_description) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT '2014 Q2' period_description UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014 Q1' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018 Q3' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016 Q1' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017 Q4' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018 Q4'
)A
```

Output is-

```
2018 Q4
```

Comment: add another value like 'adfaddfasdfdsfasdfdsfsdfsdfsa' it will return that value :)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=085cd3692dbadbe94c8b9fddc6271c4c :D

Comment: That value make any sense in the column "period description"?

Comment: you never know about garbage :)

Comment: And what logic you will apply on that value? like other's solution provided using SUBSTRING/LEFT?

Comment: those also need to convert vai otherwise those also will not work

Comment: If you accept Garbage in your table, your database/table design is also garbage :( sorry to say.

Comment: vai this column contain string so its normal somehow it may push different string rather than a period